# Airflow, Spark: RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, airflow

I am using Airflow running in a docker container on Windows and trying to read a file from hdfs:

```
sc = SparkSession.builder.appName('spark_app').getOrCreate()
csvDF = sc.read.csv("hdfs://host.docker.internal:9000/hadoop_files/example.csv")
```

It works fine in a local environment, but fails with the error in docker:

```
RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

It seems like I need to add JAVA_HOME to my Dockerfile, tried this, but it  didn't work:

```
ENV JAVA_HOME E:/Java/jdk1.8.0_321
RUN export JAVA_HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons for this problem:

1. You didn’t download a java jdk in your docker image
2. You downloaded the java jdk but its path is not known for you spark session, to solve the problem, you need to define the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` and set the jdk path in the docker image (and not in the host `E:/Java/jdk1.8.0_321`), if you have the jdk in your host, you can mount it as a volume to your docker container, and set its path to the env var.

But as an airflow user for several years, I don't recommend to execute the jobs on airflow itself, and I prefer to only schedule them using airflow, and run them on external server, in your case you can submit your job to a separate spark cluster using `SparkSubmitOperator` (http request if you use apache Livy) or execute it in a kubernetes cluster (minikube for dev). In this case you don't need to download pyspark lib and java jdk in the airflow docker image.

Comment: could you look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72608702/org-apache-spark-sql-analysisexception-illegal-parquet-type-int64-timestampn