# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Illegal Parquet type: INT64 (TIMESTAMP(NANOS,true))

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, parquet

I have a table in postgres containing a timestamp column. This table is stored in hdfs as a parquet file. When I try to read it:

```
parqDF = sc.read.parquet("hdfs://localhost:9000/hadoop_files/sample_2022_02.parquet")
```

the app fails with the error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Illegal Parquet type: INT64 (TIMESTAMP(NANOS,true))
```

Do I need to change the column type in db to something else? Or add some conversion in the app?

Answer (score 0):

The type `INT64` is not supported in the old versions of spark, try to load the file using spark 3.0.0+ (you can try with spark 2.4.x).